# Hg Merge specific commit from another branch

Tags: mercurial

I have two branches Dev and Feature1. I was working on Feature1, creating said feature, and committed it. I then wrote the code for Feature2 but committed it under Feature1 branch instead of a new branch (Feature2). So now i have two features in Feature1 branch as two separate commits, but I only want to include the second feature back into Dev.

What is the mercurial way to do this?

Comment: Have you pushed your changes to the central clone yet?

Comment: @Lasse nope, just committed locally

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Supposed you have not yet published your commits:

   If you want to merge the commit *Feature2* independent of commit *Feature1*, you should
   [move it on its own branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665549/mercurial-move-changes-to-a-new-branch/4673148#4673148).
2. If already published:

   Use the [transplant](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/TransplantExtension) extension to "duplicate" the *Feature2* commit and put it on
   its own branch. Then [backout](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Backout) *Feature2* commit on the *Feature1* branch. Now you
   merge *Feature2* independent of *Feature1* too.

In any case, instead of putting *Feature2* on its own branch, you could also put it
directly onto your *Dev* branch if this is your actual intention.

Answer (score 12):

Use `hg graft`

This command uses Mercurial's merge logic to copy individual changes from other branches without merging branches in the history graph. This is sometimes known as 'backporting' or 'cherry-picking'.

Documentation: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/help/graft

Answer (score 0):

> include the second feature back into Dev.

Include to Dev **and leave** in Feature1 - translpant, as mentioned by @oben-sonne
Move completely from Feature1 - rebase
In case you want rebase into Feature2 you'll have to create this branch (Feature1) before rebase