# Move branch start in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial

My problem is similar to [Mercurial move changes to a new branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665549/mercurial-move-changes-to-a-new-branch), but is not exactly the same.

A colleague of mine started working on a new feature and issued a few local commits. Then he noticed *"Oh well, that should go into a named branch"* and thus created one. The problem is, the commits before should have been in that branch already. So the simplified history now looks a little like this:

```
O 7: default
|
O 6: default
|
|  O 5: newbranch
|  |
|  O 4: default
|  |
|  O 3: default
| /
O 2: default
|
O 1: default
```

So *default* now has two open heads: 7 and 4. I'd like to get rid of the open head 4 but of course still have 3 and 4 merged back into the "main" *default* later on when we merge *newbranch* back into main (merging them now is undesired as it would bring changes into *default* that we don't want there yet).

The question is: what's the best way to handle this ?

Do a `--close-branch` on 5, create a new branch off 2 and re-apply revisions 3-5 ?

As far as I've understood there's no good way to simply say *"newbranch started at 3 instead of 5"*.

**Update:** Since this is has already been pulled by others I don't want to rebase the revisions in question. Forcing the colleague to recreate/switch branches would be OK since that would affect only one person instead of 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get rid of the extra default head, you could:

```
hg update -r 4
hg commit --close-branch -m "Closed extra default head.  The changes from this branch will be merged along with 'newbranch', once it is complete."
```

When you eventually merge `newbranch`, it will include revisions 3-5 plus any others that you commit on top of 5.

The only potential problem with this is that revisions 3-4 will not be labeled as part of the named branch.  If this is really important for you, then you should close both the extra default head and the `newbranch` head and start over with a new branch rooted at revision 2.

Comment: Just tried it with a small test repository and this actually does exactly what I want. Once I think about it (and see it in the MacHG graph) it totally makes sense. Thanks !